# how to change **<p>** value while changing range meter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create something like this but in this code I made a seperate function for every single **DIV** is it any another way to code which work **same**  but in less functions becuase this is possible for few steps but if we need to add multiple options so we need to write multiple function for this? I really very confused how to do this.

**Somebody help me out with this issue?**

Help me with **source code** so I can understand what I need to change.

**Thank you**

```js
// --------------x-------------------x-------------------x------------------


// -----------------x-----------------x----------------------x-------------

// Select Therepy start

// --------x--------------x-------------x--------------

// Applied Behaviour

  document.getElementById("myText").addEventListener("touchend",myFunction)
  document.getElementById("myText").addEventListener("click",myFunction)
  
  
  function myFunction() {
   var myText=parseInt(document.getElementById("myText").value)
   
   if(myText==1){
      var b=document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<p>3-9 Months</p>'
     
    }
    if(myText==2){
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<p>9-15 Months</p>'
    }
    if(myText==3){
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<p>15-24 Months</p>'
    }
    if(myText==4){
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML='<p style="color:red;">24+ Months</p>'
    }
    
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  // Effect JS
  
  
  document.getElementById("eff").addEventListener("touchend",efunction)
  document.getElementById("eff").addEventListener("click",efunction)
  
  
  /* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
  function efunction() {
   var myText=parseInt(document.getElementById("eff").value)
   console.log(myText)
   if(myText==1){
      var b=document.getElementById("effc").innerHTML='<p>None visible to anyone</p>'
     
    }
    if(myText==2){
      document.getElementById("effc").innerHTML='<p>Some, visible only to therapist</p>'
    }
    if(myText==3){
      document.getElementById("effc").innerHTML='<p>quite, visible to family as well </p>'
    }
    if(myText==4){
      document.getElementById("effc").innerHTML='<p style="color:red;">Significant, visible to everyone</p>'
    }
    
  }
  
// -------------x-----------------x-----------------x-----------------x------------  



//Sensory INtegration start


function st(){
    var wtf=document.getElementById('sit')
    if(wtf.style.display=="none"){
    wtf.style.display="block"
    }
    else if(wtf.style.display=="block"){
    wtf.style.display="none"
    }
    }




    document.getElementById("stfv").addEventListener("touchend",myFunction1)
    document.getElementById("stfv").addEventListener("click",myFunction1)
    
    
    function myFunction1() {
     var stf=parseInt(document.getElementById("stfv").value)
  
    
     if(stf==1){
       document.getElementById("stfvp").innerHTML='<p>3-9 Months</p>'
       
      }
     if(stf==2){
        document.getElementById("stfvp").innerHTML='<p>9-15 Months</p>'
      }
if(stf==3){
        document.getElementById("stfvp").innerHTML='<p>15-24 Months</p>'
      }
 if(stf==4){
        document.getElementById("stfvp").innerHTML='<p style="color:red;">24+ Months</p>'
      }
      
    }


// js Effect

 /* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */

 document.getElementById("eff1").addEventListener("touchend",efunction1)
 document.getElementById("eff1").addEventListener("click",efunction1)


 function efunction1() {
    var eftext=parseInt(document.getElementById("eff1").value)
  
    if(eftext==1){
      document.getElementById("effcp").innerHTML='<p>None visible to anyone</p>'
    //    console.log(b)
     }
     if(eftext==2){
       document.getElementById("effcp").innerHTML='<p>Some, visible only to therapist</p>'
     }
     if(eftext==3){
       document.getElementById("effcp").innerHTML='<p>quite, visible to family as well </p>'
     }
     if(eftext==4){
       document.getElementById("effcp").innerHTML='<p style="color:red;">Significant, visible to everyone</p>'
     }
     
   }


// End **
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
       <!-- ------------------x---------------------x--------------------- -->
                    <!-- Therpies start -->
                    <div class="form-group">

  
                        <div id="sth">
                          <br>
  
  
                          <input type="checkbox" id="aba" name="ABA" onclick="ra()"
                            value="Applied Behaviour Analysis">&nbsp;  <label for="aba"> Applied Behaviour Analysis</label>
                          <div id="ss">
                            <br>
                            <div style="border:2px solid #CED4DA;padding:10px;">
                              <p>How long was the teatment carried for?</p>
                              <center> <input type="range" onclick="abam" name="rang" id="myText" value="1" min='1' max="4"></center>
                              <center>
                                <p id="change" style="color:green;">3-9 Months</p>
                                
                             
                                
                                
                               
                                
                                
                              </center>
  
                              <hr>
                              <p>Positive effects of therapy visible?</p>
                              <center> <input type="range" name="rang1" id="eff" value="1" min='1' max="4"></center>
                              <center>
                                <p id="effc" style="color:green;">None visible to anyone</p>
                              </center>
  
  
  
  
  
                            </div>
  
  
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <!-- ------------------x--------------------x----------------x------------------------->
  
                          <input type="checkbox" id="siti" name="sit" onclick="st()" value="Sensory Integration Therapy">   <label for="siti"> Sensory Integration Therapy</label><br><br>
                          <div id="sit" >
  
  
  
  
                            <div style="border:2px solid #CED4DA;padding:10px;">
                              <p>How long was the teatment carried for?</p>
                              <center> <input type="range" onclick='stfvfa()' name="sitr" id="stfv" value="1" min='1' max="4"></center>
                              <center>
                                <p id="stfvp" style="color:green;">3-9 Months</p>
                                
                                
                                
                              </center>
  
                              <hr>
                              <p>Positive effects of therapy visible?</p>
                              <center> <input type="range" name="sitrr1" id="eff1" value="1" min='1' max="4"></center>
                              <center>
                                <p id="effcp" style="color:green;">None visible to anyone</p>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                              </center>
  
  
                            </div>
  
                            <br>
  
  
                          </div>
  
  
  
  
  
                      </div>
  
                      <!-- Therpies ends -->
                
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want:-> about when you move range meter so text in bottom is changing like 3-15months then 15-25months that same thing I want but for this, In this code I use multiple ID selector and created lot of functions which is kind of impossible if we need to create 1000 of this kind of conditions. so is this any another way to do this same thing? Like I create a single function and calling this in every where?

Comment: Are you talking about the error for not defining the `abam` and what effect you want to achieve?

Comment: @James he wants to use one function for all divs

Comment: @James no buddy I'm not talking about errors I'm talking about when you move range meter so text in bottom is changing like **3-15months then 15-25months** that same thing I want but for this, In this code I use multiple ```ID selector``` and created lot of ```functions``` which is kind of impossible if we need to create 1000 of this kind of conditions. **so is this any another way to do this same thing?** Like I create a single function and calling this in every where?

Comment: @iammithani yes bro !! but don't know how to do this.

Comment: check my answer that I sent

Comment: You have duplicate `id` values which makes your HTML invalid (an `id` *must* be unique within the document), you're using the `<center>` element, which is obsolete as of HTML 4.01 (we're currently in the days of HTML 5), you've got a lot of repetitive CSS in the HTML (put CSS either in the head of the document or in an external stylesheet).

Comment: @DavidThomas Right now this is not my problem rn I have to deal with javascript thank you for your suggestion. but rn I need help in js

Comment: Using duplicate `id` - or any invalid HTML - creates problems in JavaScript. Addressing the simple problems may help towards solving the bigger problems.

Comment: ok I understant this bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the simplest way to do this !**

You need to create a `DIV` for every input field with a unique `id` and then make a `function()` in which check user is in which `div` so function fetch the `id` of div and then fetch `id` of `input` field of the same div and at the end it will fetch the value of `<p>...</p>` of the same **`DIV`** and then it will change **`<p>...</p>`** accordingly.

```js
 function _cd_(ss){
           var v=ss.id //Fetching id of div container 
      
          var _v_=document.getElementById(v).firstElementChild.id 
          var _d_=document.getElementById(v).lastElementChild.id
          var _k_=document.getElementById(_v_).value
        

          if(_k_==1){
              document.getElementById(_d_).innerHTML="<p>Value 1</p>"
          }
          else if(_k_==2){
            document.getElementById(_d_).innerHTML="<p>Value 2</p>"

          }
          else if(_k_==3){
            document.getElementById(_d_).innerHTML="<p>Value 3</p>"

          }
          else if(_k_==4){
            document.getElementById(_d_).innerHTML="<p>Value 4</p>"

          }
     
       }
```

```html
  <div id="cot" onclick="_cd_(this);">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1" id="name1">
    <p id="_cv_">This</p>
</div>
    <div onclick="_cd_(this)" id="some">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1" id="name2">
    <p id="_cd_">This</p>
</div>
```

Comment: wait what? is this possible... it's just 10-15 line of code and omg.. Thannk you.. @Nishant Sharma

Answer (score -1):

Try using function parameters by doing `myFunction(this)` that passes that div as the value to that function, and use that to achieve what you want, and try making an object that stores what div should contain what on the change of what range, and what should appear on changing. Alternatively try using classes instead of ids

Also, I would suggest to use `switch case` statements instead of:

```
if (x ==1){
//..
}
else if (x ==2){
//..
}
else if (x ==3){
//..
}
```

Comment: dude I tried this too but I'm not that much pro in Js so I need your help maybe with source code.

Comment: bro I you help me with source code so please? as I told you I'm not really very much good with Javascript. If you'll need time have it !